# How to setup simple port forwarding on macOS with pf? "Rules must be in order: options, normalization, queueing, translation, filtering"

Tags: osx, port-forwarding, pf

I am trying to pass traffic from Mac A port 5800 to Mac B on port 5900 using `pf`.

This is the intended path of travel:

```
Client to port 5800 → Router (Yes, port forwarding is setup here) → Mac with PF → PF → 192.168.1.246 port 5900
```

The following is the rule I intend to use (maybe its wrong):

```
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 5800 -> 192.168.1.246 port 5900
```

### Problem 1

When I add the rule to `/etc/pf.conf` directly and run `sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf` I get:

```
$ sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
/etc/pf.conf:29: Rules must be in order: options, normalization, queueing, translation, filtering
pfctl: Syntax error in config file: pf rules not loaded
```

My config file is below:

```
#
# Default PF configuration file.
#
# This file contains the main ruleset, which gets automatically loaded
# at startup.  PF will not be automatically enabled, however.  Instead,
# each component which utilizes PF is responsible for enabling and disabling
# PF via -E and -X as documented in pfctl(8).  That will ensure that PF
# is disabled only when the last enable reference is released.
#
# Care must be taken to ensure that the main ruleset does not get flushed,
# as the nested anchors rely on the anchor point defined here. In addition,
# to the anchors loaded by this file, some system services would dynamically 
# insert anchors into the main ruleset. These anchors will be added only when
# the system service is used and would removed on termination of the service.
#
# See pf.conf(5) for syntax.
#

#
# com.apple anchor point
#
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"

rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 5800 -> 192.168.1.246 port 5900
```

### Problem 2

If I use an `anchor` with the same rule above, I get no error. However, the port is still closed and I get `connection refused` when trying to connect.  After doing some research,  I found that one possibly is that there is nothing listing on port 5800, so it is refused but

1. I don't want anything to be listening, just forward the traffic to the other computer
2. Even if `nc` is listening I still get refused from external and from internal (localhost) it doesn't forward

Comment: The syntax is wrong. The example in the `pf.conf` manual has `rdr on ne3 inet proto tcp to port smtp -> 127.0.0.1 port spamd`.  Note: No `pass`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Just tried. Makes no difference.

Comment: Also, try putting the `rdr` line before the `com.apple` comment.  `rdr` lines belong to the "translation" set of rules.

Comment: @Kusalananda I just tested. If I use a custom anchor it seems to works as is...

Comment: @Kusalananda Same error with `rdr` prepended to the comment

Comment: Same, with a syntax error? What does the `rdr` line look like now?

Comment: @Kusalananda See edit

Comment: Oh, I meant, put your `rdr` rule above the comment, following the same syntax/pattern as the example that I quoted from the `pf.conf` manual. Unfortunately I don't know enough about `pf` anchors to say anything about them, and if this does not work, we'll have to wait for some other wizard to come by.

Comment: @Kusalananda Will try. Also take a look at chat,

Answer (score 6):

As the error message states, you need to add your `rdr` rule next to the other translation rules on `pf.conf`. Since there is already a `rdr` anchor present, the best bet is to put your `rdr` rule right after it:

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr pass inet proto tcp to port 5800 -> 192.168.1.246 port 5900
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
```

(`from any to any` is implied if omitted, so I removed it for readability)

The `rdr` rule only tells the packet filter what to do with the TCP packets that arrive on port 5800.  You'd normally need a `pass` rule (i.e. a filtering rule) to tell `pf` they are allowed to come in, but it is enough to add `pass` to the `rdr` rule, hence `rdr pass`.

Note that for the packet to be forwarded, you need to enable it with `sysctl` or set it permanently in `sysctl.conf` (see `man pfctl`):

```
$ sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```